# Average grade of student temporary table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join, select-into

I have a database with the following tables:

- `Students_T` (SNo, SDedc, SAddress)
- `Courses_T` (CNo, CDesc)
- `CoursesRegister_T` (CRNo, CR_CNo, CR_SNo, CRGrade)

I need to represent the following data:

For each student show:

```
Student desc, Course desc, Course grade, Grades average
```

And I need to do this for every course that the student register in.

For example:

if student **A** is registered to course **B** and his grade is 90
and he's also registered to course **C** and his grade is 70, I suppose to get the following table:

```
A B 90 80
A C 70 80
```

The important thing is that I need to use temporary tables with `SELECT INTO` syntax and I can't figure it out.

I'm using SQL Server.

Someone know how to do that?

**EDIT:**

I already did this:

```
select CR_ST_No, ST_Desc, CR_Desc, CR_Grade
into #Grades
from Students_T
left join CoursesRegister_T on CR_ST_NO = ST_No
where CRS_Desc is not null

select *
from #Grades 
drop table #Grades
```

and it's giving me table with all data I need except the average.

When I try to change the row `select *` to `select *, avg(CR_Grade)`
it can't execute.

Comment: "I can't figure it out." Figure what out? How to use temp tables? How to select into temp tables?

Comment: "it can't execute", why not? What is the error message and what does the error tell you?

Comment: It's said - "Column '#Grades.CR_ST_No' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: And what does that error message tell you? What does it indicate?

Comment: but #Grades.CR_ST_No is part of the group by.
if i understood well what the group by means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical use case for a Window Function. You haven't provided any sample data and I can't test it right now, but something like that should work:

```
SELECT s.SDedc, c.CDesc, r.CRGrade, AVG(r.CRGrade) OVER (PARTITION BY s.SNo) AS average_grade 
    FROM Students_T             AS s 
    LEFT JOIN CoursesRegister_T AS r ON r.CR_SNo = s.SNo 
    LEFT JOIN Courses_T         AS c ON r.CR_CNo = c.CNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question and the subsequent comments, you need to change your select-statement to include a `group by` clause.

Please read through the **[MSDN SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)** article as to how a `select` statement is structure, with explanations and examples of each section.

The reason you are getting your error message is that the [`AVG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx) is an aggregate function and so requires that all columns that are not part of the aggregate, to be included into the `group by` clause of your select statement.